# Bringing a specific instagram post from a listview into a detail view

Tags: android, api, listview, arraylist, instagram

I'm using android studio to make an instagram app, which for the most part works fine. 
I can get my most recent posts into a listview, but I want to be able to click on a particular post and bring up a detail view of just that post.

I've tried doing it by passing the id through an onclick into a DetailView activity using Intent, but this just gives me a blank page. I also tried using a fragment but I couldn't get that to work either. The adapter uses ArrayList and I was trying to pass that using parcelable and then serializable but neither of those worked.

Honestly, this is my first time using android studio or even making an app for android so I'm at my wits end here.

link to GitHub for code: https://github.com/mckarlsson/Clone/tree/DetailView-Latest

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the best way but here is how I usually do this:

1. for displaying images without blocking the UI thread I use a image loader library. For instance Android Volley Image Loader. The advantage of this, for instance is that if it loads something it keeps it in cache and it's retrieved from cache when later needed
2. Since the image loaded is most likely cached based on its url, I pass the image's url as a Bundle parameter to a DialogFragment, when tapping on list item, and then in the fragment, I simply use the ImageLoader library to load the image into an ImageView.

This has some advantages, for instance, next time you start your app, the cached images will load almost instant, same for tapping on them.

Comment: It's not just the image I want though, the user name and profile picture should come with the image, and then in the new activity/fragment I will probably add the comments (if there are any).

I think perhaps the biggest problem is that I don't really understand how the post looks after the fetch function is done with it. Like, I can't find the things by id because I don't even know if they have any